# Rails 4 way of customizing model errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `Post.body` field that is required in the model but in the UI I label this field as `Details` in the form.

The error rails generated is `Body can't be blank`.

But I really want to display that error as `Please enter some Details`.

**How can I customize model errors in Rails 4?**

Answer (score 2):

The solution for a mountable engine turned out to be hidden under a giant rock...

```
# /config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      'my_engine/my_model':
        my_field: "Details"
    errors:
      models:
        'my_engine/my_model':
          attributes:
            my_field:
              blank: "can't be blank"
```

This should be in the documentation for mountable engines.

Comment: The non-engine version should a locale file as well. I find the Rails translation support to be unworkable in Real Life (try shipping a YAML file to a translation team some time...) so I use gettext and `:message` flags on all my validators.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Active Record Validations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message):

> [...] the `:message` option lets you specify the message that will be added to the errors collection when validation fails. When this option is not used, Active Record will use the respective default error message for each validation helper.

So you should be able to say:

```
validates :body, presence: true, message: 'Please enter some Details'
```

in your model.

Comment: The message generated is `Body Please enter some Details` ... Anyway to remove the `Body` and customize the entire error msg?

Comment: Is that `Body` coming from the model's errors or somewhere else? I suspect that your error display code is adding it.

Comment: The solution for mountable engines turned out to be trivial. It uses a locales file.